# Rails dataTables add link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm using an approach from Railscast to remotely access a table for dataTables.

This is the start of the code in workorders4_datatable.rb:

```
class Workorders4Datatable

delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

def initialize(view)
  @view = view
end

def as_json(options = {})
  {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Workorder.external.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: workorders.external.total_entries,
      aaData: data
  }
end

private

def data
  workorders.external.map do |workorder|
    [
        link_to(workorder.id, workorder),
        h(workorder.parent.try(:id)),
        h(workorder.description),
        h(workorder.client.try(:client_name)),
        h(workorder.woasset.try(:assetnum)),
        h(workorder.type.try(:typecode)),
        h(workorder.billmethod.try(:method_name)),
        h(workorder.workgroup.try(:group_name)),
        h(workorder.employee.try(:employee_full_name)),
        h(workorder.wostatus.try(:statuscode)),
        h(workorder.expenses.tobill.sum("quantity") * workorder.expenses.sum("unitcost")),
        h(workorder.events.tobill.sum("hours")),
        h(workorder.events.sum("hours")),
        link_to('ADD Invoice', new_invoice_path(:workorder_id => workorder), :class => 'btn btn-primary')
    ]
  end
end
```

All of it works except for this line:

```
link_to('ADD Invoice', new_invoice_path(:workorder_id => workorder), :class => 'btn btn-primary')
```

It causes this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `new_invoice_path' for #<Workorders4Datatable:0x007f94513588a0>:
```

Yet, the following works in a different view:

```
<%= link_to 'ADD Invoice', new_invoice_path(:workorder_id => @workorder.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Is there some way I can get it to work?

Comment: Ignore last comment. It is a helper delegation issue. See at the top `delegate to:@view`. That's why `link_to` is working fine but the paths aren't. You could also delegate `:new_invoice_path`, or perhaps `@view.new_invoice_path`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm not sure what you're suggesting I change.  Do I add `delegate to:@view.new_invoice_path` ?

Comment: That worked !! If you answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to replace `new_invoice_path` with `@view.new_invoice_path`? That might work. The reason is because `new_invoice_path` should be called in context of the `view`, but it's being called in context of `Workorders4Datatable`.

I've seen this pattern in the past as a shortcut:

```
def v
  @view
end

v.new_invoice_path
```